# Accessing individual array elements in php

Tags: php, arrays, html

I took some values via text box to a PHP file, now storing values in the array I had a common `name` attribute for them (text box).

Now the problem is not all my values from that arraylist is used. How should I access individual element?

```
<td><input type="number" id="tphy" disabled="disabled"  min ="0" name="sci[]"/>
<td><input type="number" id="tchem" disabled="disabled"  min ="0" name="sci[]"/>
```

Array requires a common `name=""` attribute while individual accessing requires unique `name=""`.

Comment: Sorry, it's totally unclear what you are asking. Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is vague and confusing, I believe you are looking for a way to access unique fields when some input fields may not be used. You can use an associative array in that case:

```
<?php
$fields = [ 'tphy' => 2, 'tchem' => 2 ];

function sanitizeAttribute($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
};

foreach( $fields as $field => $repeat ) {
    $repeat = range(1, $repeat);
    foreach( $repeat as $count ) {
        $sField = sanitizeAttribute($field);
        ?><td><input type="number" id="<?= $sField . "_{$count}" ?>" disabled="disabled"  min ="0" name="sci['<?= $sField ?>'][]"/><?php
    }
}
```

This will give you access to an array like this:

```
$sci['tphy'][0] // First 'tphy' entry
$sci['tphy'][1] // Second 'tphy' entry
...
$sci['tchem'][0] // First 'tchem' entry
$sci['tchem'][1] // Second 'tchem' entry
...
```